# how can we give UIImage object to UIView in iOS?

Tags: ios

hi I have searched but not getting the answer because i am new iOS..please anyone give the answer to me

```
-(void)aMethod:(UIButton*)sender{

UIButton *selectButton = (UIButton*)sender;
NSLog(@"hi %d",sender.tag);
previousButtonTag=selectButton.tag;
NSLog(@"hi %d",sender.tag);
UIImage *selectImage;
self.frameImage.image = nil;

if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
if (subButtonTag == 112) {
    self.frameImage.image = nil;
    selectImage = nil;
    selectImage = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    NSLog(@"selectImage = %@",selectImage);
    self.frameImage.image = selectImage;
   self.mainView.backgroundColor=selectImage;
}
```

i want to give that UIImage object to UIView..If i give getting exception ..how can i do this ..please anyone help me to do this
thank you in advance

Comment: Please tell me what type of value imagesArray have consiste.

Comment: simple ? what the result u need finally

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `UIImageView` instead of `UIView` and do:

```
  yourUIImageView.image = yourUImage
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.view.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"anImage"].CGImage;
```

Comment: how to apply cartoon image effects to image from gallery

Comment: @vanidasariios I can't understand you, get me more details

Comment: when we click the gallery button getting the image into image view from gallery.. now i want to apply cartoon effects to that image ..how to apply that image which is pic from gallery

Comment: cartoon effects means black and white is apply to colorful image

Comment: @vanidasariios If I don't understand incorrect,maybe you need use `UIButton` set a highlighted image which is black/white, and it is converted from CIFilter or other algorithm from the origin colourful image

Comment: i did nt get u ..please explain with clarity

Comment: i did getting image from gallery or camera ..i want to apply toon filter to the image which is getting from gallery or camera..i already downloaded and added to my app GPUImage.h file but getting error like GPUImage.h file not found..please help me to do this

Comment: how to solve the incompatible pointer types assigning to uiimage from GPUPictureImage -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   inputImage=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
  image_p=[[GPUImagePicture alloc]initWithImage:inputImage];
 GPUImageToonFilter *filter1 = [[GPUImageToonFilter alloc] init];

Comment: [image_p addTarget:filter1];
    [image_p processImage];
    self.imgView.image=image_p;
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([filter1 imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput], self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
 
[self.ipc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  
}

Comment: please anybody help me